# How to use emotion with storybook and vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, storybook, emotion

I already spent some 5+ hours and can't solve the problem

I am using in my project
vite, storybook, react, typescript and emotion for styles(css in js)

when i started storybook i got error message
**Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.**

main.js file - storybook

```
const svgr = require('vite-plugin-svgr');
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    'storybook-addon-swc',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
  },
  typescript: {
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen',
  },
  async viteFinal(config, { configType }) {
    config.plugins = [...config.plugins, svgr()];

    return config;
  },
  features: {
    storyStoreV7: true,
  },
};
```

vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
  base: '/',
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react({
      jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
      babel: {
        plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
      },
    }),
  ],
  define: {
    'process.env': process.env,
  },
});
```

my jsx

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as ImportantImage } from '../assets/important.svg';
import { ReactComponent as BookMarkImage } from '../assets/bookmark.svg';
import { ReactComponent as AttachImage } from '../assets/attach.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CheckBoxArrow } from '../assets/checkBoxArrow.svg';
import {
  Tr,
  DotMessageStatus,
  Dot,
  ImportantWrapp,
  BookmarkWrapp,
  ImageWrapp,
  Image,
  Name,
  Text,
  Title,
  Description,
  Category,
  Attach,
  MessageDate,
  AvatarSkeleton,
  CategoryEmpty,
} from './Example.styled';

import { messageCategoryImage } from '../helpers/MessageCategoryImage';
import { messageSentToday } from '../helpers/MessageSentToday';
import { firstLetterLowerCase } from '../helpers/FirstLetterLowerCase';

interface ExampleProps {
  imageProp: undefined | string;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  messageCategory: string | undefined;
  attach: { img: string } | undefined;
  serverMessageDate: string | undefined;
  read: boolean;
  messageIsImportant: boolean;
  messageIsBookMark: boolean;
  favoriteMeesage: boolean;
}

export const Example: FC<ExampleProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    imageProp,
    name,
    title,
    description,
    messageCategory,
    attach,
    serverMessageDate,
    read,
    messageIsImportant,
    messageIsBookMark,
    favoriteMeesage,
  } = props;

  const checkBox = <CheckBoxArrow id="id" fill="#fff" color="#fff" />;
  return (
    <Tr messageIsRead={read} isChecked={favoriteMeesage}>
      <DotMessageStatus>
        <Dot messageIsRead={read} />
      </DotMessageStatus>
      <ImageWrapp id="id">
        {imageProp ? (
          <Image id="id" isChecked={favoriteMeesage} image={!favoriteMeesage && imageProp}>
            {favoriteMeesage && checkBox}
          </Image>
        ) : (
          <AvatarSkeleton id="id" isChecked={favoriteMeesage} image={imageProp}>
            {favoriteMeesage ? checkBox : firstLetterLowerCase('name')}
          </AvatarSkeleton>
        )}
      </ImageWrapp>
      <Name messageIsRead={read}>{name}</Name>
      <ImportantWrapp>{messageIsImportant && <ImportantImage />}</ImportantWrapp>
      <BookmarkWrapp>{messageIsBookMark && <BookMarkImage />}</BookmarkWrapp>
      <Text>
        <Title messageIsRead={read}>{title}</Title>
        <Description>{description}</Description>
      </Text>
      {messageCategory ? (
        <Category>{messageCategoryImage(messageCategory)}</Category>
      ) : (
        <CategoryEmpty>Category</CategoryEmpty>
      )}
      <Attach>{attach && <AttachImage />}</Attach>
      {serverMessageDate && <MessageDate>{messageSentToday(serverMessageDate)}</MessageDate>}
    </Tr>
  );
};
```

and i created styles as

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

export const Tr = styled.tr<TTr>`
  transition: all var(--transition-time) ease-in-out;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.isChecked ? `var(--current-message-background-color)` : 'transparent')};
  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--current-message-background-color);
  }
  &:hover ${Dot} {
    background-color: ${(props) => (props.messageIsRead ? `var(--dot-color)` : '#005ff9')};
  }
  &:hover ${Image} {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: ${(props) => (props.isChecked ? '#005FF9' : '#fff')};
    background-image: url(arrowCheckbox);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 16, 61, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 4ms ease-in-out;
  }
  &:hover ${AvatarSkeleton} {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: ${(props) => (props.isChecked ? '#005FF9' : '#fff')};
    background-image: url(arrowCheckbox);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 16, 61, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 4ms ease-in-out;
  }
`;
```

storybook file

```
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react';
import { Example } from './Example';

export default {
  title: 'Example',
  component: Example,
};

const Template: Story = (args) => <Example {...args} />;

export const Default = () => <Example />;

export const Checked = Template.bind({});

export const Hower = Template.bind({});
```

doesn't work with props either.

```
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react';
import { Example } from './Example';

export default {
  title: 'Example',
  component: Example,
};

const Template: Story = (args) => <Example {...args} />;

export const Default = () => (
  <Example
    imageProp={undefined}
    name="name"
    title="title"
    description="some descp"
    messageCategory="travel"
    attach={{ img: 'string' }}
    serverMessageDate="2022-05-03T11:00:03.088Z"
    read={false}
    messageIsImportant={false}
    messageIsBookMark={false}
    favoriteMeesage={false}
  />
);

export const Checked = Template.bind({});

export const Hower = Template.bind({});
```

i tried using import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
as they say on google

But I am getting an error,Even if the style file is empty and there is only this import

error message
**missing ) after argument list**